# How to filter values when I have float numbers in string

Tags: python

We have a string that contains float numbers:

```
A = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
```

How can I compute the the number of items with values >3.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non for loop way. This is the ideal pythonic way:

```
A = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"

# Split the values into a list
to_filter = A.split(', ')

new_A = [i for i in to_filter if float(i) > 3.0]
print(new_A)
```

**Outputs:**

```
['3.03', '3.35', '3.46', '3.23', '3.5']
```

You can also replace the list comprehension with this:

```
new_A = [float(i) for i in to_filter if float(i) > 3.0]
```

This outputs the values as floats:

```
[3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 3.23, 3.5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Split your strings, and then for each item of your new list cast them to floats ^^

```
float_strings = A.split(", ")

counter = 0
for f in float_strings :
   if float(f) > 3:
       counter += 1
```

Comment: You should see my pythonic way that uses a list comprehension. It helps you and the OP to learn a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
A = [1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85]

i = 0
while i < len(A):
    if(A[i] > 3):
        print(A[i])
    i += 1
```

The output will be as shown below.

```
3.03
3.35
3.46
3.23
3.5
```

You can find the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/LFDS67503).

Answer (score -3):

`var A="1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85";`

`var d = A.split(",")`

**with for:**

`

```
for(var i = 0; i< d.length-1; i++){
    if(d[i]> 3.0){
    console.log(d[i]);
    }
}
```

`

**with foreach**

```
d.forEach((x)=>{
  if(x> 3.0){
   console.log(x);
   }
  });
```

Comment: This is Javascript, not Python.